# PhoneGap Build: Plugins not working (getting "undefined" errors) on Android

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I've got a really nasty problem here. Every time, I try to use the file and file-transfer plugins in my project, I get the *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataDirectory' of undefined* error while trying to get the data directory with `store = cordova.file.dataDirectory;`    . Now, I've been trying to solve my problem for hours, but I couldn't find any help. I'm also using the Barcode Scanner plugin in this project an it's working like a charm. I am using PhoneGap 3.6.3 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.4. Since i'm new to PhoneGap, it's likely that I'm missing something important...

I've included the plugins in my config.xml like this:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.1" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.6" />
```

Maybe this could be a hint: The PhoneGap Build log for Windows Phone is confirming that the plugins are being added. But it appears that they're not being added to the Android build, since I can't find any reference of them in the build log.

Windows Phone Log:

> Adding www\plugins\org.apache.cordova.file-transfer\www\FileTransfer.js
>
> Adding www\plugins\org.apache.cordova.file-transfer\www\FileTransferError.js
>
> Adding www\plugins\org.apache.cordova.file\www\File.js

This is a part of my index.js, excluding the Barcode Scanner functionality.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', this.downloadFile, false);
        document.getElementById('scan').addEventListener('click', this.scan, false);
        document.getElementById('encode').addEventListener('click', this.encode, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },


    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    downloadFile: function(){       
        //The directory to store data
        var store;

        //Used for status updates
        var $status;

        //URL of our asset
        var assetURL = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4s8mnkfwdqylns/test.txt?dl=0";

        //File name of our important data file we didn't ship with the app
        var fileName = "test.txt";
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
        function init() {
             $status = document.querySelector("#fileStatus");

            $status.innerHTML = "Checking for file";

            store = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

            //Check for the file. 
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(store + fileName, appStart, downloadAsset);

        }

        function downloadAsset() {
             var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
             console.log("About to start transfer");
             fileTransfer.download(assetURL, store + fileName, 
         function(entry) {
             console.log("Success!");
             appStart();
        }, 
        function(err) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.dir(err);
      });
    }
    function appStart() {
        $status.innerHTML = "Datei aktuell";
    }
},

// [...Functions for Barcode scanner...]
};
```

I've also included the phonegap.js file in my index.html:

```
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
</body>
```

I really hope someone can help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've always thought that you need to first call

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
```

for *cordova.file* stuff to get defined and to be able to call *resolveLocalFileSystemURL*.

So in your case, try this modification

```
function onFileSystemSuccess() {
    store = cordova.file.dataDirectory;

    //Check for the file. 
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(store + fileName, appStart, downloadAsset);
}
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I applied your modification and now it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined`. :D

Comment: Oh, sorry, copied it from my production code where the _LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT_ equals to 1, so please change it to 1 simply to fix that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't resolve the issue. Do you have any other idea? I can't think straight anymore. But I will check back tomorrow. Maybe, I'll have to reduce the code to just the `cordova.file`and `cordova.file-transfer` stuff in order to find the issue.

Comment: Well, in that case, are you sure your deviceready event is triggered? I have had hard time with it not triggering for odd reasons. I was finally able to make some sense on my problems when I started using [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) to remote debug my app, you should try that if not already using remote debugging of built apps.

Comment: @tyso89: Were you able to solve this problem? It would be nice to get the final answer here for future reference! :)