# PhoneGap Build: cordova.file-transfer download always fails with code 3 on Android

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

It's exasperating.. A few days ago, I was unable to get the Cordova file-transfer Plugin to work with PhoneGap 3.6.3. Now it seems that the issue with the "undefinded" errors has been resolved after I've rewritten the index.js. This is the old issue: [PhoneGap Build: Plugins not working (getting "undefined" errors) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572160/phonegap-build-plugins-not-working-getting-undefined-errors-on-android)

Now I've encountered a new problem: The download on Android always fails with the following message:

> FileTransferError
>
> body: null
>
> code: 3
>
> exception: null
>
> http_status: 401
>
> source: "http://www.hs-bremerhaven.de/fileadmin/images/logo.png"
>
> target: "file:///data/data/de.testapp1374839/files/logo.png"
>
> **proto**: Object

I already tried adding these featue-tags to the config.xml file:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
```

And I provided a wildcard to access external ressources.

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

This is my updated index.js:

```
var DR = {
    initialize: function(){
        this.bindEvents();
    },
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', this.downloadFile, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function(){
},

downloadFile: function(){
    console.log("Downloading...");
    var $status = document.querySelector("#fileStatus");;
    var assetURL = encodeURI("http://www.hs-bremerhaven.de/fileadmin/images/logo.png");
    var fileName = "logo.png";
    var DEV_PATH = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
    var fullPath = DEV_PATH + fileName;
    console.log("DEV_PATH " + DEV_PATH);
    $status.innerHTML = "Checking for file";

     window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fullPath, onFilePresent, downloadAsset);

    function onFilePresent(){
        console.log("File already there");
    }
    function downloadAsset() {
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        console.log("Downloading: " + assetURL + " to " + fullPath);

        fileTransfer.download(assetURL, fullPath, 
            function(entry) {
                console.log("Success!");
                onFilePresent();
            }, 
            function(err) {
                console.log("Error");
                $status.innerHTML = "Fehler.";
                console.dir(err);
            });
      } 
   },
  checkFile: function(){
       //todo
  }
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 401 error is unauthorized, so, maybe your server doesn't allow to download files

Comment: @jcesarmobile: I don't think that is the case since you are able to download it with browser straightaway.

Comment: Was a solution ever found to this problem ? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with this earlier, when I hadn't added the 5th parameter for *download* method just like you. I didn't, though, check the error messages on that and then got it working and after all removed whole File Transfer, so can't verify.

Anyway, this parameter is called [*trustAllHosts*](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md#download) and it defaults to *false*. So passing *true* as fifth parameter worked for me. Please give it a try and lets figure out more if that doesn't make it work.

Also, since you on this question you refer to the last question you asked, please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) answer there if it did help you to solve your problem as you claim on title.